# colormap scatter plot dependant on cluster membership

Tags: python, matplotlib, cluster-analysis, scatter-plot, colormap

Im conducting soft clustering on a data set and I wanted to create a cool graphic that looks similar to the image posted. I want to show a data points membership between two (or more clusters) in graphical form. Im not really sure how to go about this however. Ive used criteria to assign colours to a data point, but am unsure how to create a more dynamic sort of graphic seen below. Any help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think [markers](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html) are just the thing your looking for:

```
x1 = y1 = 1
x2 = y2 = 2

dx = np.random.rand(10)
dy = np.random.rand(10)

x = np.array([x1 + dx, x2 + dx]).ravel()
y = np.array([y1 + dy, y2 + dy]).ravel()

threshold = 4
markers = np.array(["o" if xy > threshold else "h" for xy in x + y])


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for marker in np.unique(markers):
    index = markers == marker 
    ax.scatter(x[index], y[index], marker=marker)
```

[image]

Adding someaditional code to control color and transparency (alpha)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x1 = y1 = 1
x2 = y2 = 2

dx = np.random.rand(10)
dy = np.random.rand(10)

x = np.array([x1 + dx, x2 + dx]).ravel()
y = np.array([y1 + dy, y2 + dy]).ravel()

threshold = 4
markers = np.array(["o" if xy > threshold else "h" for xy in x + y])

blue_color = "midnightblue" # predefined
pink_color = "orchid"  
colors = [blue_color if marker == "o" else pink_color for marker in markers]

alphas = np.array([abs(xy - threshold) for xy in x + y])
alphas = 1 - alphas/np.max(alphas) 


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(len(x)):
    ax.scatter(x[i], y[i], marker=markers[i], color=colors[i], alpha=alphas[i])
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for the reply. I wanted to ask a way to create a scatter plot like the one in my link on my original post. So the closest to the centroid is dark blue and as data points go further away they get lighter. Finally the data point that is half way between two centres is sort of a mix between the two colours that defines the two clusters, so in my image i posted its green and blue. If you are able to guide me with regards to that i will be greatful as i dont really know how to code it

Comment: I added some more functionality to control color and transparency. I suggest you play around with the variables and find a set up you like. Personally I am not very fond of your original image, and I don't know how to replicate it exactly. Hope you can figure out how to achieve your preferred outcome!

Comment: You could add the parameters [size, facecolor, and edgecolor](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter) to your example, as the markers in the OP's question differ in these aspects as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `GaussianMixture` in `scikit-learn` does something close to what the question asks.

Specifically, `predict_proba(X)` returns an array with the probability of each point in `X` belonging to the component. In the example below we fit two mixture components, so the last two plots should be opposites of each other:

```py
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, _ = make_moons(noise=0.05)

mix = GaussianMixture(n_components=2).fit(X)
probs = mix.predict_proba(X)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey=True)
ax[0].scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1])
ax[1].scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=probs[:, 0])
ax[2].scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=probs[:, 1])
plt.show()
```

[image: Three scatter plots of the synthetic moons data set. Left shows the original data, middle shows probability of being in cluster 0, right is the exact opposite of the middle.]