# Gaussian Mixture Model Plot for Soft Assignment by Color

Tags: cluster-analysis, gaussian-mixture-model

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRTSs.png))

I want to show soft assignment by probabilities from GMM looking similar to the image posted. I want to show a data points membership between two (or more clusters).

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried to multiply probabilities from maximum of predict_proba(X) but it seems not working as it is not applied to labels=0.

ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=labels*probability)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [colormap scatter plot dependant on cluster membership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71580741/colormap-scatter-plot-dependant-on-cluster-membership)

Comment: (It's the exact same graphic at least. I added an answer addressing the Gaussian Mixture model [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74803727/12439119)).