# What do the c and cmap parameters mean in .scatter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am working on PyTorch framework, in that i came through this code and have doubt on it!

```
# Create a dataset with Scikit-Learn's make_moons()
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
num_samples = 1000
RANDOM_SEED = 42

X, y = make_moons(n_samples=num_samples,
                  noise=0.07,
                  random_state=RANDOM_SEED)
len(X), len(y) # here X is a MATRIX features and y is a labels
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.scatter(x=X[:,0],
            y=X[:,1],
            c=y, # <---
            cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu) # <---
```

what does `c=y` and `cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu` do?

Comment: Hi there  StackOverflow is good for Q&A, but there are several points raised in this question that are better answered in the matplotlib [`pyplot.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) documentation. Briefly: `c` is a vector showing how to assign colors, and `cmap` is a colormap or color palette. A demo with the `make_moons` function is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71580741/colormap-scatter-plot-dependant-on-cluster-membership/74803727#74803727).

Answer (score 1):

c = y is an argument passed to the scatter function in the matplotlib. It specifies that the values in the y array should be used as the color data for the plotted points.

while cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu is a color map argument that can be passed to certain functions in the matplotlib. The cmap argument specifies the color map to use for visualizing data. The color map RdYlBu stands for Red-Yellow-Blue